# Работа с иероглифами в PHP (gb2312)

Tags: php

Добрый день.

Делаю для сайта поиск. Вводим русские символы, через бинг перевожу и получаю иероглифы, которые нужно вставить в урл и перейти по нему. Вместо `rawurlencode($result)` пробовал и `urlencode($result)` и просто отсылать. В итоге в урле иероглифы кодируются так: `%EF%BB%BF%E7%9F%AD%E8%A3%A4`, а должны так: `%B6%CC%BF%E3`. Сами иероглифы для примера взял : `短裤`. По русски шорты.

Как правильно и какой функцией подготовить их для перехода?

```
$value=iconv("windows-1251", "UTF-8", $_POST['text']); // То, что вы хотите перевести
$appid="F0F6345C7A5063103E0693B1CBA6CE231CEF5BA7"; // AppID от Бинга, который вы получили после регистрации
$from="ru"; // С какого языка будем переводить
$to="zh-CHS"; // На какой
$result=file_get_contents("http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Ajax.svc/Translate?appId=".$appid."&from=".$from."&to=".     $to."&text=".urlencode($value));
$result = str_replace("\"","",$result);
echo $result;  // получили иероглифы, правильные все норм.
echo mb_detect_encoding($result); // говорит в кодировке UTF-8

echo mb_convert_encoding($result, 'utf-8', 'gb2312'); // Попытка переконвертировать так, выводит пустой результат
$result = iconv('UTF-8', 'gb2312',$result);  
echo $result ; // А вот так показывает иероглифы норм

echo mb_detect_encoding($result);  // Но вот тут нам говорят что кодировочка то не GB2312 , а ANCII !!!

echo urlencode($result); // и скорее всего из-за ANCII тут пусто.

//А вот если сделать так:
$result = iconv('UTF-8', 'gb2312','&#24773;&#20387;');   // т.е передать иероглиф прямо текстом (вставьте любой иероглиф, система меняет его)
echo urlencode($result); //  то получим правильный урл енкоде.  ПОЧЕМУ? ((
```

Answer (score 1):

Решено!
Просто перед иероглифами была какая-то невидимая инфа и перед ними кодировались еще 2 символа. Реплейсом удаляю их и все